# Getting [object object] from action.payload

Tags: reactjs, redux

When I am dispatching getUser action generator. I am getting Is there any problem in my code?

```
//ACTION

export const getUser = (uid) => dispatch =>{

    console.log('hellow from getuser');
    return axios
            .get(`url/${uid}`)
            .then((res) =>{
                const userData = res.data;
                console.log(userData);
                dispatch({
                    type: USER_DETAILS,
                    userData
                });
            }
        )
};

//REDUCER

const userReducerDefaultState = [];

const userReducer = (state = userReducerDefaultState, 
action) =>{
console.log(action.userData); //*1
switch(action.type){
    case 'USER_DETAILS':{
        console.log('hi'+{...action.userData}); //*2
        return[
            ...state,
            action.userData
        ]
    }
```

When I am dispatching getUser, I am getting "Hi[object object]" from *2 console.log.
But got the below data from *1 Console.log. This is the desired data from *2 also.

```
bio:null
followers:[]
followings:[]
name:"saheb"
posts:(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
__v:0
_id:"y08RxtsHeacQTwiuNTAA"
```

Comment: The `+` operator will coerce arguments to string by calling the `toString()` method. Try `({}).toString()` in your console. It will return '[object Object]'. So, this shouldn't be much of a surprise. If you want to log the object to console, you need to pass it as a separate argument (as _@Zenp_) suggested or log it in a new console statement.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
console.log('hi',{...action.userData})
```